# Redefining the length-related commands to have a decimal coefficient

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

The macro of `\!` is defined as: `\def\!{\mskip-\thinmuskip}` and the command of `\thinmuskip` is initialized as being `\thinmuskip = 3mu` (Appendix B: p.349, The TeXBook). I couldn't have found the definition, so how does the command is defined? I mean, I know the command is defined in [WEB language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEB), but is there a way to redefine this into a TeX-Like language as well?

Also, is it possible to re-define the LaTeX macro command of `\!` in a way to "accept" a value somehow (eighter by providing the value before the command (i.e: `4\!`) or by enclosing it inside of curly braces (i.e: `\!{4}`)) to instruct the command to generate a negative space *four times* wider than a normal invocation would have generated?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify your first question please? What do you mean by "how does the command is defined"? Which command, `\!` or `\thinmuskip`? And isn't the definition the one you show in your question?

Answer (score 2):

`\thinmuskip` is set to 3mu by default in `fontmath.ltx` which is read in while the format is being made, the last few lines of which are:

```
\thinmuskip=3mu
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `fontmath.ltx'.
```

So you can use \thinmuskip=5mu to have a bigger default or to set an arbitrary value something like `$a\mkern -6mu b$` is a negative space twice the default `\!`

Comment: Can you make `\mkern -6mu` as a LaTeX macro with an arbitrary argument instead of `-6` integer?

Comment: @Qaher `\newcommand\zzz[1]{\mkern#1mu\relax}`  then `\zzz{7.5}`

Comment: I have `\def\scalefactor{-.16667}‎` and ‎`\newcommand{\yyy}[1]{\kern{#1*\scalefactor}em\relax}‎` then `a \yyy{2.2} b` for example, gives error. How such a command can be executed and work well in LaTeX format only for text mode with any real number?

Comment: @Qaher please don't ask new questions in comments, note \kern is not the same thing as  `\mkern` but you want something like `\newcommand{\yyy}[1]{\kern#1\glueexpr\scalefactor em \relax}`

Answer (score 2):

`\mskip` and `\thinmuskip` are TeX primitives, so they have no definition: they are part of TeX.

If you want to have multiples of `\thinmuskip`, you can do as follows.

```
\newmuskip\normalnegthinmuskip
\normalnegthinmuskip=-\thinmuskip

\catcode`@=11
\def\!{\afterassignment\makenegthinmuskip\count@=0}
\def\makenegthinmuskip{\mskip\ifnum\count@=0 \else\count@\fi\normalnegthinmuskip}
\catcode`@=12

$a\!b$

$a\!4 b$

\bye
```

Be sure to leave a space between `\!` and a following digit if you don't want a bigger negative skip, but to typeset the digit.

[image]

Comment: +1 for your answer. But it seems the command `\mskip` has been defined and initialized inside of the `tex.web` file (using the WEB language, of course!)

Comment: @Qaher `\mskip` is a primitive. Just like `\end` or `\vskip`. There's no “initialization”.

Comment: You just said “so they have no definition” in the answer, (and I thinks it's not true). Even though I don't know how WEB commands work (It's not necessary for me I believe), but there should be a place to define a concept or a command to use it somewhere in codes. By the way, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Qaher Unexpandable primitives such as `\mskip` are passed directly to the typesetting processor for action. This action is not available at the user level.